# how to combine 2 json in query

Tags: ios, json, objective-c, swift, xcode

I need to append 2 JSON.
Currently it is printing as two separate Json.
How do I combine both of my reading???? I want my Json to have both the readings together.

```
let query = HKSampleQuery(sampleType: glucoseType!, predicate: predicate, limit: 5, sortDescriptors: nil) { (query, results, error) in
                for result in results as! [HKQuantitySample] {
                  let bloodGlucose = result.quantity.description
                  let bloodGlucoseItem = HealthDataItem(endDate: result.endDate, value: String(bloodGlucose), startDate: result.endDate, type: .bloodGlucose)
                          let healthData = [bloodGlucoseItem]
                          do {
                            let data = try JSONEncoder().encode(healthData)
                            let json = String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
                            for i in 0..<results!.count {
                              if (i != 0){
                                json!.append(json!)
                              }
                              print("json data:", json as Any )
                            }
                            resolve(json)
                          } catch {
                               //error handling
                          }
                }
            }
```

console:

```
json data: Optional("[{\"value\":\"8 mg\\/dL\",\"endDate\":635390040,\"startDate\":635390040,\"type\":\"bloodGlucose\"}]")

json data: Optional("[{\"value\":\"8 mg\\/dL\",\"endDate\":635390040,\"startDate\":635390040,\"type\":\"bloodGlucose\"}]
[{\"value\":\"8 mg\\/dL\",\"endDate\":635390040,\"startDate\":635390040,\"type\":\"bloodGlucose\"}]")

json data: Optional("[{\"value\":\"6 mg\\/dL\",\"endDate\":635393640,\"startDate\":635393640,\"type\":\"bloodGlucose\"}]")

json data: Optional("[{\"value\":\"6 mg\\/dL\",\"endDate\":635393640,\"startDate\":635393640,\"type\":\"bloodGlucose\"}]
[{\"value\":\"6 mg\\/dL\",\"endDate\":635393640,\"startDate\":635393640,\"type\":\"bloodGlucose\"}]")
```

Comment: You have two array (in JSON Stringified in sample; but I guess that `healdData` is an Array already), just `append(contentsOf:)`? And use a DispatchGroup, `enter()`, `leave()` and `notify()` if they are async.

Comment: I tried to use append method. it prints the same data again. (check my updated question)